# average of order_demand for each product as output - MapReduce - Java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i am new to the mapreduce topic and still in the learning phase. i thank you in advance for the help and further tips. in the context of an exercise at the university i have the following problem:
from a csv file (listed below as an example) i want to calculate the average order_demand for every single product_code.

the codes, shown below "FrequencyMapper" & "FreqeuencyReducer" are running on my server and i think i currently have a display problem of the output.
since i am making my first beginnings with mapreduce i am grateful for any help.

listed below are the mapper, reducer and driver codes.

Example of the Dataset (csv-file)

```
Product_Code,Warehouse,Product_Category,Date,Order_Demand
Product_0993,Whse_J,Category_028,2012/7/27,100
Product_0979,Whse_J,Category_028,2012/6/5,500 
Product_0979,Whse_E,Category_028,2012/11/29,500 
Product_1157,Whse_E,Category_006,2012/6/4,160000 
Product_1159,Whse_A,Category_006,2012/7/17,50000
```

My goal for example:

```
Product_0979   500
Product_1157   105000
...
```

FrequencyMapper.java:

```
package ma.test.a02;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

public class FrequencyMapper
  extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
 
 @Override
  public void map(LongWritable offset, Text lineText, Context context)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     
    String line = lineText.toString();
    
    if(line.contains("Product")) {
        String productcode = line.split(",")[0];
        
        float orderDemand = Float.parseFloat(line.split(",")[4]);
        
        context.write(new Text(productcode), new IntWritable((int) orderDemand));
    }
  }
}
```

FrequencyReducer.java:

```
package ma.test.a02;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;

public class FrequencyReducer extends Reducer< Text ,  IntWritable ,  IntWritable ,  FloatWritable > {
     public void reduce( IntWritable productcode,  Iterable<IntWritable> orderDemands,  Context context)
         throws IOException,  InterruptedException {
             
      float averageDemand  = 0;
      float count = 0;
      for ( IntWritable orderDemand : orderDemands) {
          
            averageDemand +=orderDemand.get();
            count +=1;
        }
      
      float result = averageDemand / count;
    
      context.write(productcode,  new FloatWritable (result));
    }
}
```

Frequency.java (Driver):

```
package ma.test.a02;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Frequency {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: Average <input path> <output path>");
      System.exit(-1);
    }
    
    // create a Hadoop job and set the main class
    Job job = Job.getInstance();
    job.setJarByClass(Frequency.class);
    job.setJobName("MA-Test Average");
    
    // set the input and output path
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    
    // set the Mapper and Reducer class
    job.setMapperClass(FrequencyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(FrequencyReducer.class);
    
    // specify the type of the output
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);
    
    // run the job
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats your current output?

Comment: my output "part-r-00000" is 0.
the file is also 0 Bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tip 1**: In the mapper you have filtered lines that contains "VOLUME" in the following line:

```
if(line.contains("VOLUME")) {

}
```

But no line contains "VOLUME" so you have no input in reducer!

**Tip 2**:  your reducer output value is `FloatWritable` and you should use this line in your runner(`Frequency` class):

```
job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);
```

instead of this one:

```
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

**Tip 3**: In reducer change this line:

```
public class FrequencyReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable ,  IntWritable ,  IntWritable ,  FloatWritable>
```

To this one:

```
public class FrequencyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable,  IntWritable, FloatWritable >
```

Also add these lines to the `Frequency` class:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

**Tip 4**: fist line in your csv file which describe the structure of your csv file will cause problem. reject this line by putting following line at the first of your map methd:

```
if(line.contains("Product_Code,Warehouse")) {
    return;
}
```

**Tip 5**: In the real program make sure that you have plan for `String` that can not be cast to `Integer` in `orderDemand`.

At the end your mapper will be :

```
public class FrequencyMapper
        extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable offset, Text lineText, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        String line = lineText.toString();

        if (line.contains("Product_Code,Warehouse")) {
            return;
        }

        if (line.contains("Product")) {
            String productcode = line.split(",")[0].trim();
            int orderDemand = Integer.valueOf(line.split(",")[4].trim());
            context.write(new Text(productcode), new IntWritable(orderDemand));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is your reducer:

```
public class FrequencyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable , Text, FloatWritable > {
    public void reduce( Text productcode,  Iterable<IntWritable> orderDemands,  Context context)
            throws IOException,  InterruptedException {

        float averageDemand  = 0;
        float count = 0;
        for ( IntWritable orderDemand : orderDemands) {

            averageDemand +=orderDemand.get();
            count +=1;
        }

        float result = averageDemand / count;

        context.write(productcode,  new FloatWritable (result));
    }
}
```

And here is your runner:

```
public class Frequency {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: Average <input path> <output path>");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        
        // create a Hadoop job and set the main class
        Job job = Job.getInstance();
        job.setJarByClass(Frequency.class);
        job.setJobName("MA-Test Average");

        // set the input and output path
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        // set the Mapper and Reducer class
        job.setMapperClass(FrequencyMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(FrequencyReducer.class);

        // specify the type of the output
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

        // run the job
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your request
i change "VOLUME" to "Product" and the outputclass, but now i get another problem with a Failed Job

i think i choiced some lines the difficult way :S

Comment: i uploaded a screenshot of my error.
in which log file i can find the error line?

Comment: Follow other Tips I added in the answer.

Comment: i fixed the points and now i get a output and i get each product_code with the order demand (update in the question)

Comment: sry i dont understand Tip 5 - what do you exactly mean with Float and orderDemand?

Comment: I added complete iimplementationto my answer. I tested it and it works well.

Comment: its work great! thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: the code is working, but when i input the same data with 500.000 lines i become a failed error. you can see the message in the question! do you know why i get for 30 lines no failed error and for 500.000 lines an error?

Comment: In Tip 5 I mentioned that you should check if data can be cast to `Integer` in the following line of code in the mapper: `int orderDemand = Integer.valueOf(line.split(",")[4].trim());` Here the error happened because you have a line in your code like `Product_0993,Whse_J,Category_028,2012/7/27,(1) `  and we can not cast `(1)` to `Integer`